# Calculating radius of the circle

Tags: triangles

A perfect circle sits exactly within a right-angled triangle,dividing its hypotenuse into two segments of 3 and 10 units.

The area of the triangle is 30 square units.

What's the radius of the circle, "r" ?

[image]

Comment: Nice homework screenshot; could you at least rewrite the text as text? Also, show us your attempt so that we can assess your level of knowledge

Comment: Orville and Wilbur are sending a message here......

Comment: @JanDvorak, Sorry added now..I'm way passed the school days so not getting the way to solve this..

Comment: so, no progress solving this? Not even some thoughts?

Comment: Sorry Jan not yet.. tried but nothing coming :(

Comment: Sorru, I suck at geometry, but shouldn't one cathete be at least 3 and the other one at least 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center of the triangle is called the [incenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter). The circle is called the incircle. The center is the intersection of the angle bisectors.

using your drawing let A,B,C be the vertices on top, left and right respectively.Call the incenter I. let a,b,c be the points the circle intersects with sides BC,AC,AB respectively. Then Ab=Ac,Ba=Bc and Ca=Cb. Therefore AB=3+x and BC=10+x. Also $BC*AB=60$ so $(3+x)*(10+x)=60\rightarrow13x+x^2=30\rightarrow x=2$.

So now we know its a right triangle with sides $13,12,5$.

And know you can use Ye Olde formula $r=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}
$

where s is half of the perimeter.

Comment: For this case, $r=x$ because $BcIa$ is a square of side $r$.